# What is the opinion of Islam regarding the attendance of women in mosques? (is it Mustahab or Makruh)?

Tags: women, masjid

What does Islam mentions regarding the presence of women in going to the mosques and also is it a Mustahab (recommended) or Makruh (better not to do, but not haram)?

Actually does Islam persuade them to stay home or go to the mosques?

(Is there any narration about it?)

Comment: What does mustahab mean??? Anyways, I've heard some one quote Hadith, saying it is better for women to pray at home, although they're allowed to go to mosques. (Don't remember which Hadith, and also don't know if the Hadith is authentic enough)

Comment: Mustahab means recommended. Actually a Mustahab practice is a practice which is nt mandatory (wajib), but you'll achive reward or thawab if u do that. / in regards to the attendance of women at mosques once I heard a similar hadith such what you said, but I am not sure regarding that as u r not sure about its authenticity)

Answer (score 3):

Women can go to mosque but it is important that mosque has separate area for offering prayer. But generally women can go to mosque and it is Mustahab.

There are some Hadith related to this matter.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If your women ask permission to go to the mosque at **night**, allow them." 
> *[Sahih al-Bukhari 865 - Vol. 1, Book 12, Hadith 824](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/256)*
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) said, "Allow women to go to the Mosques at **night**."
>
> *[Sahih al-Bukhari 899 - Vol. 2, Book 13, Hadith 22](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/23)*

**Night** : Sensitive time one which nobody usually walks and go out. Our Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is letting women go to mosque even at night time.

Comment: doesnt this mean to allow them only at night?

Comment: You would allow your kid to go out side but you won't let him go at night. Mentioning night time to put strength in massage, i.e. "**Even if** they want, let them go in night. That means they shouldn't ask for permission at morning.